# Match end of line if line contains specific text

Tags: regex

I doing trying to extract words from an end of a line if a line contains a specific phrase using RegEx.
For example I have these lines:

```
Web Mode .............................. Enable
Secure Web Mode.............................Enable
AP Fallback ................................ Enable
```

And I would like to find the lines starting with `"Web Mode"` for example and if the line starts with `"Web Mode"` I would like to match the word at the end of the line which in this case is `"Enable"`.

I have been able to match the beginning of the line like so:

```
^Web Mode.*
```

but I'm stuck at this point, any Ideas?

Comment: Like this? `^Web Mode \.+ (\S+)$` https://regex101.com/r/5UxDR8/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example data, you could use a capture group to match `Enable`

```
^Web Mode \.+ (\S+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `Web Mode`  Match literally followed by a space
- `\.+` Match 1 or more occurrences of a dot
- `(\S+)` Match a space char capture 1+ non whitespace chars in group 1
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5UxDR8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```php
^Web Mode.*\b\K\w+$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/UfsnBd/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Web Mode                 'Web Mode'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```